# Not able to access JSON in EJS template inside script

Tags: node.js, plotly, ejs

I am trying to build a webapp which renders dynamic charts based on JSON passed from node to client side.

However I am not able to access json variable inside `<script>`. I have tested JSON object using

```
console.log(<%= data %>)
```

it is appearing there.

My Node code looks like:

```
let ltlasJSON = JSON.parse(ltlasData);

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.postalCode;
    var url = "http://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/" + query;

    request(url, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            var adminDistrict = data["result"]["codes"]["admin_district"];
            var filtered = ltlasJSON.filter(a=>a.areaCode==adminDistrict);
            res.render("results", {data: filtered});
        }
    }
    );    
});
```

results.ejs:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Engliand Covid-19 </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- Plotly.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


    <h1>Results Page</h1>


    <script>
    var specimenDate = <%= data.areaCode %>
    var cases = <%= data.dailyLabConfirmedCases %>
    var data1 = [
            {
                x: specimenDate,
                y: cases,
                type: 'bar'
            }
        ];
        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am new to node and ejs. End goal is to pass array of JSON (two fields) in x and y variable of plotly object.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the output or error?

Comment: You can directly pass `data` to `Ploty.newPlot('myDiv', data)`

Comment: @PrathameshMore testJSON is not defined

Comment: @PrathameshMore I can't as you can see data1 contains lay out info as well - bar plot.

Comment: @PrathameshMore modified my ejs file now. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'"

Comment: Is this working `var specimenDate = <%= data.areaCode %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214973/discussion-between-prathamesh-more-and-bhavesh-ghodasara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1) You are passing the data incorrectly to the frontend javascript. `<%=` is always wrong because it encodes HTML entities, but we are in a JS script tag and not in regular HTML. Instead, you want to pass it as JSON using `JSON.stringify`, and use `<%-` to prevent HTML-encoding:

```html
var specimenDate = <%- JSON.stringify(data.areaCode) %>
```

This still has two issues though: Firstly, `JSON.stringify(undefined)` will produce `undefined` (and not a string) which becomes an empty output after `<%-`, so you will get a syntax error in case the value was undefined. Secondly, a string containing `</script>` will escape the script block and wreak havoc. I'd recommend using something like [`devalue`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/devalue) instead of `JSON.stringify`.

2) You are accessing `data.areaCode`, but I see that `data` actually comes from `filtered`, and `filtered` is the result of an `Array.prototype.filter` call, which returns *an array* of all matching elements. Yet, you are accessing the `areaCode` property as if `data` was directly one of the matching elements, not an array of all matching elements.

If it is intended that you have an array there, you have to loop over its entries, or access one directly, for example `data[0].areaCode` (but also you have to make sure `data[0]` is always existing).

If this is not intended, then you just used the wrong array method. You can use `Array.prototype.find` to return the first match or `undefined` otherwise.

Example:

```js
const db = [
  { areaCode: 1, text: 'A' },
  { areaCode: 2, text: 'B' },
  { areaCode: 2, text: 'C' }
]

console.log(db.filter(el => el.areaCode === 1)) // [{ areaCode: 1, text: 'A' }]
console.log(db.filter(el => el.areaCode === 2)) // [{ areaCode: 2, text: 'B' },
                                                //  { areaCode: 2, text: 'C' }]
console.log(db.filter(el => el.areaCode === 3)) // []

console.log(db.find(el => el.areaCode === 1)) // { areaCode: 1, text: 'A' }
console.log(db.find(el => el.areaCode === 2)) // { areaCode: 2, text: 'B' }
console.log(db.find(el => el.areaCode === 3)) // undefined
```